# Slice chaining JavaScript

Tags: javascript, chaining

Just encountered this while posting an answers, and did not figure out why this happens.

Here is the code:

```
var s = "aaaaaX..";

var a = s.slice(1);
    a = a.slice( 0, a.lastIndexOf("X") );    

var b = s.slice(1).slice( 0, s.lastIndexOf("X") );    

var c = s.slice(1).slice( 0, s.lastIndexOf("X") - 1);

console.log(c);
```

Why is `a` not equal to `b` ?
Why does the `-1` have to be added so that `c == a` ?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mb974/

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes, you are right, just figured that out myself but decided not to delete the question as others might encounter the same problem. :)

Comment: Because the `s` in the `s.lastIndexOf("X")` refers to the unmodified `s`, not the `s.slice(1)`. The `.slice()` method doesn't mutate the original. EDIT: ...sorry, my original wording was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have removed one first character from `s` and assign it to the `a` variable. So index is lower by 1 than index in string where you didn't remove first character.

Following example will work:

```
var a = s.slice(1);
    a = a.slice( 0, s.lastIndexOf("X") );    

var b = s.slice(1).slice( 0, s.lastIndexOf("X") ); 

// a == b
```

Comment: I believe OP wanted `aaaa` instead of `aaaaX`, but just a guess.